# Upgrade node 0.12.x to nodejs 4.4.x using pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I use [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io) to run my node processes in production (on Ubuntu 14.04).  After upgrading from **node 0.12.x** to **nodejs 4.4.x**, the command to run node(js) changed from `node` to `nodejs`.  [I followed the instructions on the nodesource distribution installation instructions.](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions)

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

PM2 still wants to call `node`, even though the newer version uses the command `nodejs`.  I hacked it by replacing the node binary with a sim link like this:

```
mv /opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/node /opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/node.old
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/node
```

and this seems to work fine.  But would prefer to simply change a config in PM2 to point to the new binary.

What is the best way to make pm2 compatible with an upgrade to nodejs 4.4.x?

**Update**: these are the places where `node` exists on this server

```
root@ip-172-30-1-190:/usr/bin# find / -name "node" -type f
/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/node
/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/node
/usr/local/bin/node
/usr/local/n/versions/node/4.4.1/bin/node
```

I originally tried to upgrade node using npm and the `n` package [using this tutorial](https://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs), which accounts for the `/usr/local/n/versions/node/4.4.1/bin/node` line.

Comment: FYI [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) is a breeze!

Comment: @soyuka [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) solved my problem - and it is very well documented and current!  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NVM, which is a NodeJS package manager with many contributors and acceptance by the NodeJS community.  https://github.com/creationix/nvm

This question is also answered on Stackoverflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12570971/404699

*Caveat*:
`nvm` installs into a user's home directory.  So if you use another tool to manage node processes, such as **pm2**, then you need to specify the new name of the node process (`nodejs` vs `node`) in order to experience the version nvm sets (if going from v0.12.x to v4.x for example).  This is because nvm links `node` to `nodejs` only under the installed user's profile.

Answer (score 0):

If you had `node` and `nodejs` on your system, why did you remove `node`?
What is `/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/node`? That is no official path to neither `node` nor `nodejs`.

When installling node.js 4.x, Ubuntu configured your system so that `node` is just an alternative name for the new `nodejs` binary to not break existing systems. So in your case, you should not have had to create the symlink.

This is how your system should be configured:

```
root@server:~# update-alternatives --get-selections | grep node
js                             auto     /usr/bin/nodejs
node                           auto     /usr/bin/nodejs
```

Since you manually deleted the `node` link, the output of the above command may be the same, but it is probably broken. Unless you need the *Amateur Packet Radio Node program (node)*, I would suggest that you repair it and let Ubuntu maintain symbolic links determining default commands.

```
# Remove the symlink and remove the rest of a broken "update-alterantive" configuration:

unlink /opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/node
unlink /opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/node.old
update-alternatives --remove-all node
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10
```

Comment: I put the `node` binary back the way it was using `mv node.old node` and then ran the last two lines of your final code block, the lines with `update-alternatives` (did this in a sandbox EC2 AMI for testing).  However, the problem with PM2 calling `node` instead of `nodejs` persists.  I also added some more additional information at the end of my OP.  [This instance was originally a prepared instance from Bitnami, which I turned into an EC2 instance.](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00GXYEEA4)

Comment: It turns out someone created an entire package centered around a 2500 line bash script purposed for upgrading node and managing various node versions.  It's well documented and up to date.  This solved my problem:  https://github.com/creationix/nvm